# How can I make text that looks like a link run a controller function when clicked?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple link that a user clicks on when they need to get a password reminder:

```
<a ng-click="forgotPassword()">Forgot your password?</a>
```

I tried this but it does not seem to work. I would like the functionality of a link, the look of a link (with an underline appearing on hover) but do not want to have the /# appear in the bottom of the browser when I hover.

Can anyone suggest some ways that I could achieve this with AngularJS?

Comment: You could use a span with desired css styling an add the ng-click directive to this span element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<span class="link" ng-click="forgotPassword()">` tag. Style it with `text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;`, the color you like, etc.